# Set hyperlink in excel sheet using Node js

Tags: node.js, json2xls

I have converted JSON data to excel in node js using the json2xls package. The Excel file was prepared properly but I want to add a hyperlink for some cells in the sheet.

So it is possible using json2xls or any package in node js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried myself and it looks not possible using that library. You can either make a pull request to it to support FORMULA type or parse JSON yourself and use a node.js library to create XLSX files. (i.e. : https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx)

Comment: Yes, I tried xlsx and achieved using this library.